# Laravel Eloquent Conditional inside Query like PLSQL

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to do conditional statement inside Laravel query, is it possible?
In PLSQL I would do the following to do IF ELSE, can I do it in Laravel Eloquent ?

```
select *
from x
where x.id = 1
and ( (varName = 'all') OR  (x.name = 'red') )
```

What's happening up there is user is picking from a drop downbox (varName), and is either picking all colors as 'all', or picking individual colors.

I know it would be easy to write two IF Else statements and duplicate the SQL with each condition, but I have a really big SQL, and don't want to duplicate the whole SQL twice just for something simple. Is it possible to do this in Laravel? Or are there other ways to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use whereRaw for this, for example

```
...
->where('x.id','=',1)
->whereRaw('(varName = "all" or x.name="red")')
...
```

Please note that the raw query isn't escaped by default, so make sure to do this if your handling user input.